# How to structure such a plugin?

Tags: craft3

I am running an app project, which consists of three "components".

1) The app itself

2) Laravel API serving the data for the app

3) Marketing website based on Craft CMS

Now I plan to extend the Craft CMS website with landing pages for all records of the API.

So for example there should be a new url like this:

```
https://example.com/more-about-{slug}
https://example.com/more-about-tarifa
```

The Craft system should not know about the available slugs / landing pages. Craft should only take this slug, call the API to fetch the information (content, images, ...) and show it in a template.

Can anyone of you give me some advice how you would realize this?